# Copy Spells creating a logic paradox

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

So with the addition of Order of Scribes wizard  I read about its abilities, since I heard a claim that they can potentially be better evocation wizards than the school subclass itself. While reading, however, I came across something more interesting.

So the 2nd level ability of the Scribe wizard is that you can create a magic quill. This quill comes with a number of benefits, but the one I'm interested in says that the quill does not require ink to write. It also has an effect on copying spells into the book by reducing the time it takes significantly, but I mention this simply to show that the quill is able to be involved in the process.

So the question that came to mind is this: if the quill requires no ink to write, then what happens to the gold cost of copying spells? I knew that special ink was involved with that cost but upon checking the reasoning given by the book it also says that the cost covers component costs as well. Ok, but what if my character has a component pouch? Or an Arcane focus?

So for example, say I find a scroll containing Flaming Sphere and I want to copy it down as a Scribe wizard. Naturally I would use my quill to make it faster and not have to use ink, but the components are, as written, "a bit of tallow, a pinch of brimstone, and a dusting of powdered iron". It doesn't have a gold cost and the components aren't consumed upon use so my component pouch should have what I need every time I need it, since that is how it has been deemed by Crawford himself to function. So where is this 50 gold cost coming from?

I may be interpreting something wrong but from what I'm seeing, so long as the spells components aren't consumed or have an unusual gold cost to them, as a Scribe wizard i shouldn't need to spend anything to copy over spells into my book while using the quill. Am I missing something or is this really a looping paradox?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Have a look at the [tour] and visit the [help] in case you need further information about posting questions/answer! I think you may find the answer to your question [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177551/63061).